# Rails update Database with change in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, schema

I want to try to apply a one to one relationship between two models inside Rails.

In modelX.rb file i added `belongs_to :modelY`. In modelY.rb file I added `has_one :modelX`

Does the database schema change automatically? Or do I need to run a command for this association to be committed?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

You can only use these methods (e.g. belongs_to) when you have made necessary changes ( usually with migrations ) in your data structure to support these relations.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in Rails, usually, the database don't 'see' the relationship between the two entities with foreign keys and so on. The 'intelligence' of the relationships should be present on your models (as you already did using the belongs_to, has_one, etc).

Also, in order to have the schema changed you need to run the rake tasks for the database as,
rake db:migrate, db:rollback, etc.

For more information about this you can also check the 
[Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity)

cheers.